# How to pass value to a helper function?

Tags: vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm trying to create a helper function that I can reuse in my application to validate a date object.

date.js

```
export default {
  methods: {
    dateValidation (date) {
      console.log('date :', date)
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

component.vue

```
<label class="p p--bold">Beschikbaar vanaf
  <input
    v-model="form.date"
    class="p-solliciteren__input"
    type="name"
    @blur="$v.form.date.$touch"
  >
</label>
dateValidation: {{ $v.form.date.dateValidation }}

import dateValidation from '@/mixins/customValidators/date'
export default {
  auth: false,
  layout: 'notLoggedIn',
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        date: ''
      }
    }
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      date: { dateValidation }
    }
  }
}
```

If I type something in the date field I get:

> date : undefined

So the helper function is being called correctly but it's not receiving any value from Vuelidate. I kinda expected the value the `form.date` to be passed through the validation to the helper class but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

Component:

```
import { dateValidation } from '@/mixins/customValidators/date'
```

date.js:

```
export const dateValidation = (value) => {
  console.log(value)
}
```